# How does the flow works in elasticsearch queries?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have written a query which has couple of condition as shown below.

```
     GET /agreement/_search
        {
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "multi_match": {
                    "query": "T-0668",
                    "fields": [
                      "agreecondition.agreementId",
                      "agreecondition.conditionContractId"
                    ]
                  }
                },
    ,
            {
              "range": {
                "agreecondition.validFrom": {
                  "gte": "02/18/2019"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "agreecondition.validTo": {
                  "lte": "03/07/2019"
                }
              }
            }
              ],
              "filter": [
                {
                  "terms": {
                    "agreecondition.promotionId.keyword": [
                    "x",
"y"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
```

My question is how the flow works?

Ex: Does the ES first gets the results for the must condition's multi-match and on the output of the multi-match, does the range condition applies? followed by filter(on top of the output of the range condition)?

I just wanted to get a clarity on this, if my assumption is wrong, then i need to re-write the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check [elasticsearch official blog on query execution order](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-query-execution-order) to understand this in details but you might just not get all the details you are looking for, due to limitation elastic put as mentioned at the end of the blog:

> Q: How can I check which query/filter got executed first?

A: We don't really expose this information, which is very internal. However if you

> check the output of the profile API, you can count how many times
> nextDoc/advance have been called on the one hand, and matches on the
> other hand. Query nodes that have the higher counts have been run
> first.

**Note: [Profile API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-profile.html) will be very handful for you as suggested in the blog as well.**

Comment: Thank you. Sure i will do check. But order is not concrete if i understand it correctly. This might leads to improper result then